# File.Copy and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, file-copying

I have a little problem with the `File.Copy` method in WPF, my code is very simple and I get an exception when I run it,

```
Could not find a part of the path 'Images\37c31987-52ee-4804-8601-a7b9b4d439fd.png'.
```

where `Images` is a relative folder.

Here is my code, as I said simple and the same code works fine in a console application, no problem at all.

```
string filenamae = System.IO.Path.Combine(images, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(imageFile)); ;
System.IO.File.Copy(imageFile, filenamae);
this.ImageLocation = string.Empty;
```

So if any can help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Does the images folder exist? File.Copy doesn't create it automatically.

Do you know what your current directory is? File open/save boxes can change that. So it's always safer to work with absolute paths.

Do a

```
Path.GetFullPath(filename)
```

and see where that points to. Is it the right location?

Comment: and even with your method, the exception is still there.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the absolute instead of the relative path, does it work then?

Comment: the folder is in the same directory of the application, why need to be absolute, and besides why it works fine in a console application. that's what stopped me. why? What is the difference between a WPF App and a console App

Comment: "why need to be absolute" -- Because your current directory will not always be the same as your EXE directory? The command prompt lets you start an EXE from a directory other than the current dir. Shortcuts let you specify the startup directory. In either case, do you really want your app to crash? Relative paths are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: "why need to be absolute" - maybe you should try it and see if it works, then worry about why need to be absolute.

Comment: what if my absolute path doesn't exist, say i choose "d:\Images", but the 'd' drive doesn't exist, then i have to let the drive letter until tha app is deployed. don't want that.

Comment: "what if my absolute path doesn't exist, say i choose "d:\Images", but the 'd' drive doesn't exist, then i have to let the drive letter until tha app is deployed. don't want that. – abdelkrimnet 7 hours ago" What do you mean by this? Your app will always need to check if the original file exists and if the location where you want to copy to exists.

Answer (score 1):

Before you access a file, you should call System.IO.File.Exists().  It's not clear from your error description if the origin file exists or not before the copy.

If you don't specify an absolute path, your relative path with often be resolved from unexpected places, usually the current working directory of the process.  Calling this method may tell you were the process is currently running:

System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

You should never make assumptions about the current working directory of a running process as the user could start your program from anywhere.  Even if you think you always control the current working directory, you will be surprised how often you will be wrong.

Comment: Adding the System.IO.File.Exists is the best method of checking for a file prior to accessing it.  This prevents exceptions that consume time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a debugger? Why not insert a breakpoint and check the values used at each step?

If the file system says "cannot find file", I wouldn't bother arguing with it...

Comment: both the values are correct. in fact, in a console app it works fine.

Comment: When you say console application, do you mean 'not an winforms application' or do you mean 'in debug mode'? Whatever, try writing the values to the event log in the case where your code is NOT working...

Answer (score 0):

use \\ for the file path directory if it in local.. if your file exists in network path use \\\\(atfirst).. So that it look for network drive..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to embed all external files into the executable and change your code to work with these embedded files rather than to expect files on the disk.

To use images or whatever you need files("xml/txt/doc"), you need to set the build action of your file to Embedded Resource, and call the method with the fully qualified name of the file, where the name is assembled like this:

[RootNameSpaceOfTheProject].[NameOfFolderInTheProject].[FileNameWithExtension]

Example:

[image]

Call the method:

var b = ResourceOperations.GetResourceAsByteArray("Store.Resources.EmbeddedIcons.toolbox.png");
Now you can write the byte array to a temporary file for example and use this as an image source, or you can build an image from the byte array directly. At least, you've got your data...

and to save this files to a disk we should write a code by @[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) :

```
 public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
 {
     // Insert null checking here for production
     byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
     {
         output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
  }
```

then call it:

```
   using (Stream input = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
   using (Stream output = File.Create(path))
   { 
      CopyStream(input, output);
   }
```